# plsql - having trouble printing % correctly with dbms_output

Tags: plsql

I have the following code:

```
dbms_output.put_line('Calculated value: ' || trunc(v_ele * 100) || '%  Threshold: 90%');
```

Instead of the two spaces between % and Threshold, tabs are inserted. Adding a space between ' and % solves this problem, but I don't want that space there.

Also, I should note that the % sign is getting printed. It's the two spaces as mentioned above that are being printed as tabs.

Comment: This is not a PL/SQL problem, I'm pretty sure it's your SQL client that messes up the display (works fine for me with `sqlplus` and my JDBC based client). Which SQL tool are you using?

Comment: sqlplus call within a ksh script

Comment: If your client program changes string, try to use `chr(37) || ' Threshold ...'`

Comment: @Dmitry I have changed the line to `...*100) || chr(37) || '  Tresho...` and the same issue is happening.

Comment: I'm thinking this must be a KSH issue then.. are you able to post a small ksh example of what you are doing?